# Horizontal scrollbar crops the left elements when number of elements are increased

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

I am trying to make a horizontal scrollbar which will have elements used for filtering images. The elements could be like all, app, web etc. and the images will be filtered accordingly. The filter works fine but as soon as the number of elements in the scroll bar increase then the left elements start to crop.

working-

[image]

not working(the scrollbar has cropped "all" and "app" elements)-
[image]

HTML-

```
  <div class="scrollmenu">
                   
    
                 
                    <ul id="portfolio-flters" class="d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
                      
                      <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">All</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-app">App</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-card">Card</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                      <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
    
                      
                    </ul>
               
                  
                  
                </div>
```

CSS-

```
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
 
}

.portfolio #portfolio-flters {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}



.portfolio #portfolio-flters li {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #444444;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: ```as soon as the number of elements in the scroll bar increase then the left elements start to crop.``` What is your question then?

Comment: I want to add more elements without cropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add display:flex and it will work.

```
div.scrollmenu {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      overflow-x:auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      white-space:nowrap;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      width: 500px;
     
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

On my pc works fine, just add the class portfolio to the main div.

And since you are using flex classes, add justify-content-start